# Manipulating array data in reducer function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to figure out a way to store data that i've manipulated into redux state.

I have two time interval objects, parsedTime and busyTime. I used a nested loop to find available times. I don't know how to store it in a immutable way.

```js
const initialState= {
    availableTime:[],
    parsedTime:[]
    }

export default function(state=initialState,action)
{
    switch(action.type){
        case RESET:
        return initialState

        case GET_AVAILABLETIME:

        var selected=[]
        for (let i=0;i<action.parsedTime.length;i++)
        {
            for (let j =0 ; j<action.availableTime.length;j++)
            {
                if (action.parsedTime[i].start<=action.busyTime[j].end && action.busyTime[j].start <= actions.parsedTime[i].end)
                {
                    continue
                }
                selected.push(action.parsedTime[i])
            }
        }

        return {
            ...state,
            availableTime: selected,
        };
    default:
        return state;
    }
}

//dispatch function
export const getAvailableTime = (date, tech,treatment) => async dispatch =>{
    dispatch({type:RESET})
    var newDate = moment(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    var timeMin = newDate+'T00:00:00.000Z'
    var timeMax = newDate+'T23:59:00.000Z'
    //parsing time
    var times =["01:00","01:30","02:00","02:30","03:00","03:30","04:00","04:30","05:00","05:30","06:00","06:30","07:00","07:30","08:00","08:30","09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30",
                    "13:00", "13:30", "14:00","14:30","15:00","15:30","16:00","16:30","17:00","17:30","18:00","18:30","19:00"
                    ,"19:30","20:00","20:30","21:00","21:30","22:00","22:30","23:00","23:30"]
    var parsedTime =[]
    for(let i =0 ; i<times.length; i++)
    {
        var startTime = moment(newDate+"T"+times[i]+":00.00","YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SS")
        var endTime = startTime.add(treatment,'hours')

        var ret ={ start:startTime._i, end:endTime.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SS")}
        parsedTime.push(ret)
    }

    //
    axios.get('/api/calendar', {
        params: {
            timeMin: newDate+'T00:00:00.00Z',
            timeMax: newDate+'T23:59:00.00Z',
            technician : tech,
        }
    })
    .then (res=>{
        dispatch({type:GET_AVAILABLETIME, payload:res.data, parsedTime:parsedTime});
    })
    .catch (error =>{
        console.log("error")
    })
}
```

Whenever I dispatch GET_AVAILABLETIME, availableTime array get concatenated with the previous array.

Comment: The business logic should not sit here in the reducer. The arrays elements shouldn't concatenate, probably the logic that you are having inside those for loops makes it that way. To store it in an immutable way you just need to do: `return state.set('availableTime', fromJS(selected))` fromJS is from `immutable`.

Comment: Can you share how this one is triggered? (Action dispatch code)

Comment: @MaciejTrojniarz I have added the dispatch code above

Comment: @VincentLaw I don't see in the dispatch action `GET_AVAILABLETIME` anything about busyTime